# Another proof of Euler inequality via the half-angle formulas

Tags: reference-request, inequalities

The [Euler's inequality](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersInequality.html) is an immediate consequence of [Euler's identity in a triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry),

> $$OI^2=R^2−2Rr.$$

An additional proof of the Euler's inequality is given at [Elias Lampakis, Am Math Monthly, 122 (9), November 2015, p 892](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/EulerInequality.shtml). Now, continuing with [this madness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456365/the-theoretical-importance-of-the-half-angle-formulas) of deriving ***everything*** from the [half-angle formulas](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2020/06/another-proof-for-two-well-known.html), we offer an alternative proof of Euler's inequality.

> **Theorem (Euler)**: If $R$ and $r$ are the circumradius and, respectively, the inradius of a triangle, then
> $$R\geq2r.\tag{1}$$

**Proof**. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the sides of $\triangle{ABC}$. Denote $s$ its semiperimeter and $\angle{BAC}=\alpha$. It is easy to show that
$$(s-a)\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=r.\tag{2}$$
Also, it is well-known that
$$\frac{abc}{4\Delta}=R\qquad and \qquad\Delta=\frac{bc\sin{\alpha}}{2},\tag{3}$$
where $\Delta$ is the area of $\triangle{ABC}$. Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{abc}{4\Delta}&\geq(-a+b+c)\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\\\frac{abc}{4bc\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}&\geq(-a+b+c)\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\\abc&\geq(-a+b+c)(4bc\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}})\\abc&\geq(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)\end{aligned}$$
This is [Padoa's inequality](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Padoa.shtml), so the proof is complete.

**Question: Is this proof of Euler's inequality known? Any reference?**

Crossposted at [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480296/another-proof-of-euler-inequality-via-the-half-angle-formulas).